# Escape character in JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, escaping, jtextfield

I was wondering if there's a simple way to deal with escape characters in a JTextField. The thing is that getText() will escape the escape character. Of course, that will be the preferred behavior most of the time, but not if you want to allow the users to freely provide a delimiter for a CSV file (including \t). Any ideas?

Bob

Comment: put into a temp string add another \`\\` to every \`\\` present to unescape it and thus allow \n to show in `println()` execution or whatever else.

Answer (score 1):

You can always override the behavior of any and all public functions in a swing component. Its called "specialization". For example, you can create your own `MyJTextField` class and override the `getText()` method.

Answer (score 0):

JTextField is only a View so it always has a model inside it, this model is `Document` class. You can try this:

```
    JTextField f = new JTextField();

    // your JTextField is being filled somehow with text ...

    Document document = f.getDocument();
    try {
        String text = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
    }
```

Maybe when you collect text from `Document` instance instead of `JTextField` instance it won't be escaped;

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be kind of late for you, but I found an easy solution to that problem:

```
JTextfield field = new JTextField();
/*someone puts a string into it*/
escapeFulString = field.getText().replace("\\t","\t");
System.out.println(escapeFulString);
```

This will print out that string with all the tabs. To add any other escape sequences just do that same process.
Just don't forget, java string methods DO NOT edit in place, e.g.:

```
text.replace("\\t","\t") 
//is not the same as
text = text.replace("\\t","\t");
```